# ActiveMQ failed to start (IOException)

Tags: cmd, activemq-classic, startup, ioexception

I've been using ActiveMQ for a few weeks now and every time I boot up my laptop, I always just use `activemq start` to start it but today it throws an error:

```
Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ, java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in
JMX: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind)
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is already another ActiveMQ instance running so the new one cannot bind to that server socket just as the exception tells you.  Kill the previous instance and then you can start a new one.

Comment: I tried using the command 'activemq stop' and then 'activemq start' again but that didn't work. Any other way?

Comment: Use the system process manager to locate the AMQ process and terminate it, pretty basic stuff.